# Cannot replay YouTube video on mobile twice when rel=0

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, mobile-safari

The `rel` parameter in YouTube API dictates whether or not related videos are shown at the end. When `rel=0` the video reverts back to the thumbnail with a play button.

However on mobile (tested on iPhone / iPad / Fire Tablet) when the video goes back to the thumbnail it cannot be played a second time. It just does nothing.

I [reported the issue to Google](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7523&can=4&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary) but nothing yet after a few days.

I had to resort to destroying the video and recreating it but this makes for a kind of nasty flickering.

My experience with YouTube issues is they never seem to end up fixing anything related to iOS - so I was wondering if there was any other kind of trick to prevent this.

[Test page](http://defenderrazor.com/webtests/youtube_second_playback_disallowed.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with refreshing a webpage at a specific interval is that you dont know exactly when the video ends so you need to develop a method which the video player sends a signal when the video ends, which would then start the script to refresh the page. Otherwise you end up restarting it in the middle of the video. so personally, I would not even mess with refreshing the page. For Audio players it works ok because audio is smaller and streams more quicker. Video dont.... they always stop to buffer.
So YouTube API uses `"Events"` and `"Listeners"`, so in particular, you need to design around the Event: `"onStateChange"`.

`When onStateChange = "ended"` (zero) the video has ended, so then you reload the video player with the same video and set it to its Ready State again.
In theory its very easy you basically need to setup and control the entire video player through javascript. And the API gives examples on that.

```
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html
http://grizzlyweb.com/webmaster/javascripts/refresh.asp
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/forum/
```

Comment: regarding the refreshing I mean to just remove the IFRAME on the page and replace it with a new IFRAME. I wasn't going to refresh the entire page. This approach actually is working OK for me but I figured I'd just found a bug - and to be frank I'm kind of surprised this has received so little attention. Doesn't anyone every try to play a video twice on mobile?

Comment: Maybe they just refresh the page and load it again? :)
And maybe with time there's going to be much more attention regarding this.  This is one possible solution, maybe sometime in future there's going to be another. Feel free to mark my answer accepted :)

Comment: it's basically a bug in youtube but nobody there seems to care - a video with a red play button should be playable! I'm pretty sure this broke recently as I never noticed it before

Comment: Maybe it's not a bug. But, we'll wait and see what happens. Someone is going to ask this or similar question again,or maybe refer to this. I can't wait to see what solutions are going to be then.

Comment: Ok it definitely WAS a bug ;-) But I just realized that it was possible that Google had independently fixed it without anybody commenting on my bug report - and I'm glad to report that that indeed is what happened. So now I can play the video multiple times and don't have to completely destroy and recreate the video when it ends :-) Phew :-)

Comment: Then, maybe this topic is going to be closed because the BUG was fixed :) Nice one if they fixed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `loop` and `playlist` parameters as well. You can set playlist parameter to video ID and same video can be replayed using this.

So, it will be something like:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/{VIDEO_ID}?wmode=opaque&loop=1&version=3&playlist={VIDEO_ID}

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

#### Appears to have been fixed by YouTube.

I can now play the video multiple times (on multiple devices) without it getting stuck. Was too busy wondering why my question was getting so little attention that I forgot to check again to see if it was fixed ;-)

Comment: uh oh! why is this getting upvoted now - please tell me it didn't break again!